# Combining different geometry types in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, combine, geometry-data-type

Two geodatabases have been created using split by attribute tool from CAD drawing file. One gdb is from polyline layer and another from polygon layer of input drawing file.

I want to combine contours which are polygons in one feature class and contours as polylines in another feature class. 
Or 
Is there a tool to import similar layers based on 'Layer' filed of CAD drawing irrespective of geometry type into a new output gdb ?

Comment: You cannot place polygons in a line feature class or lines in a polygon feature class. Period. This is one of the fundamental differences between CAD and GIS. It's easier to save polygons as lines than to build topology from line to polygon, but if you need polygons, that can't be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> You cannot place polygons in a line feature class or lines in a
>   polygon feature class. Period. This is one of the fundamental
>   differences between CAD and GIS. It's easier to save polygons as lines
>   than to build topology from line to polygon, but if you need polygons,
>   that can't be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to store multiple geometry types in the same feature is more of a storage format limitation.  Many GIS storage formats support different geometry types in the same geometry. For example you can store multiple geometry types in PostgreSQL/PostGIS "Geometry" data type.  Oracle and SQL Server can do the same row by row geometry type variations also.  Each GIS package may have it's own limitations on how it works with these multi-geometry type fields.